# android call listener from service will not respond when activity closes

Tags: java, android, service

I am creating application which contains service that suppose to listen to calls,
and pop up an alert dialog after call has ended, the issue is, that as long as the activity running or in the background, the service works and the dialog pop up, but when I close the activity, the dialog wont pop up, as like the listener will not listen anymore to calls.
need help please!

this is how I call the service from my activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.start:
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), PhoneService.class));
        break;

    case R.id.stop:
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), PhoneService.class));
        break;
    }
}
```

the service class:

```
public class PhoneService extends Service {



private static String TAG = "SERVICE";
int currentState;
Context context;
String incomingNumber;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

// starts the service
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "FirstService started");



    context = this;

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); // TelephonyManager
                                                            // object
    CallListener listener = new CallListener();
    telephony.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    // keeps the service going until explicitly stops
    return START_STICKY;
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "FirstService destroyed");
}
```

the listener class:

```
public class CallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {



        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // Incoming call handling
            Log.i(TAG, " ring ring ring" + incomingNumber);
            currentState = state;

        }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // Outgoing call handling and answer
            Log.i(TAG, " ofhook" + incomingNumber);
            currentState = state;

        }
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            // Device back to normal state (not in a call)
            Log.i(TAG, " idle" + incomingNumber);

            if (currentState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"phone number dialed is "+ PhoneService.this.incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setMessage("Who is this person?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("1",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(
                        DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("0",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(
                                            DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.getWindow().setType(
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                alert.show();

            }

            currentState = state;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your service to derive from `IntentService` and remove the overrides for `onBind` and `onStartCommand` (let the system handle those).

Put your code in the `onHandleIntent` override.

The different service types are handled differently - a bound service only operates while the activity is running, but an intent service can be started at any time. You can read more about service types [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: Well I tried that but I see that the service stops after his work is done while I need is a service that will always listen to call events until I will stop it explicitly, I tried to put the onHandleIntent in a while (true) but not working..